# Tool for enumerating list indices in libreoffice writer

Tags: libreoffice

I have a file in libreoffice writer that has lines like this:

1. text
2. text
3. text

Sometimes I have to add new in between lines so I get something like this

554. text

new text

555. text

I would like to know if there is a tool of libreoffice writer that corrects automatically the order so that I get this:

554. text
555. new text
556. text

It is important that there is a blank line between the enumerated lines.

Making this manually becomes tedious when I have to reenumerate 400 lines or more.

Answer (score 1):

Libreoffice Writer is an extremely powerfull tool. Getting to know the tools you need takes a bit of learning. Take a look at fields, and in particular Variables ("Number range") to insert numbers that automatically update if a field of the same type is inserted later.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is using [numbered lists](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/guide/using_numbered_lists2.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=UNIX). Using this feature, LO Writer will prepend every paragraph with a number, and it will adapt the number if you insert or delete numbered paragraphs.